# Laravel checkbox checado ou não checado conforme Banco de dados

Tags: laravel, checkbox

preciso de uma ajuda no Laravel de como "checar os checkboxes" de um formulário. Tenho uma tabela cores, hoje com 12 cores diferentes mas pode ser quantas eu quiser . E uma uma tabela corproduto. O cores.id = corproduto.cor_id. Quando eu cadastro o produto eu escolho as cores que ele terá. Até aí tudo certo. Porém quando faço a edição deste produto, gostaria que viesse a lista de todas as cores e a que são usadas(checadas).
Verifiquei este link, https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/getting-a-checkbox-checked mas não consegui. A imagem abaixo é do cadastramento. Agradeço qualquer ajuda. Valdir

[image: Tela de Cadastramento de Produtos, escolhendo as cores]

Comment: Eu faria um `left join` da tabela cores para a tabela da relação, verificava os que são `null` que são os que não teve cadastro, rodava um `foreach` no resultado com essa diferença

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isso, é necessário primeiramente que você tenha os relacionamentos corretamente configurados no seu model.

Por exemplo:

```
class Cor extends Eloquent {

}


class Produto extends Eloquent {
    public function cores() {
       return $this->hasMany(Cor::class, 'cor_id');
    }
}
```

Se você estiver usando o `Form::model` do Laravel, você precisa simplesmente fazer assim:

```
{{ Form::model($produto) }}

 @foreach($cores as $cor)
    {{ Form::checkbox('cores[]', $cor->id) }} {{ $cor->nome }}
 @endforeach

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Ao fazer isso, automaticamente as cores que estiverem presentes no relacionamento do `Produto` serão marcadas no checkbox.

Se por conta de nomenclaturas internas for complicado fazer da form acima, você também tem a opção de utilizar o método `contains`, presente no `Collection`.

Veja:

```
 @foreach($cores as $cor)
    {{ 
       Form::checkbox(
           'cores[]',
           $cor->id,
           $produto->cores->contains($cor->id)
       ) 
     }}
     {{ $cor->nome }}
 @endforeach
```

Essa resposta se aplica se você estiver usando o Laravel 4, ou o Laravel 5 juntamente com a biblioteca Laravel Collective. Se não estiver usando, você vai ter que fazer o `if` na mão, no HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Existe então um relacionamento `Muitos para Muitos` (**N:M**), onde as **tabelas** `Produto` e `Cores` possui um tabela intermediária com suas respectivas chaves:

**Model** `Cor`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cor';    
    protected $fillable = array('descricao');    
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';    
    public $timestamps = false;  

    //relação muitos para muitos.
    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Produto::class,'produto_cor','cor_id', 'produto_id');
    }
}
```

**Model** `Produto`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'produto';    
    protected $fillable = array('description', 'cor_id');    
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    //relação muitos para muitos.
    public function cores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Cor::class,'produto_cor','produto_id', 'cor_id');
    }
}
```

**No** `Controller`

```
public function index()
{
    $id = 1; // código do produto
    $result = Cor::leftJoin('produto_cor', function($join) use ($id)
        {
            $join->on('produto_cor.cor_id', '=', 'cor.id')
                ->where('produto_cor.produto_id', (int)$id);

        })
        ->select(\DB::raw('cor.id, cor.descricao, if(produto_id is null, 0, 1) corstatus'))
        ->orderBy('cor.descricao')
        ->get();
    return view('test.index', compact('result'));
}
```

na variável `$result` retornar a ***lista de cores*** com um campo extra ***corstatus*** aonde `corstatus = 1` a **cor** está presente naquele produto, diferente não.

E finalmente **na** `View`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel - Test</title>
    {{ Html::script('js/jquery.v1.11.0.js') }}
</head>
<body>
    @foreach($result as $r)     
        <div>
        <input @if((int)$r->corstatus==1) {!! 'checked="checked" ' !!} @endif type="checkbox" name="cor[]" value="{{$r->id}}">{{$r->descricao}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá Virgílio já tenho uma tabela intermediária "corproduto" que contem um campo cor_id (ref. tabela cores,um para um) pois não posso repetir as cores, e um produto_id (ref. tabela produtos, um para muitos) o produto para varias cores. Não tenho o campo "corstatus", pois não consegui salvar da View(form) o checkbox false. Usei o Input::get('cor') , claro ele só "pega" os checados, Alguma informação adicional eu já agradeço. Kaztyx.

Comment: Então, você tem um erro de design no seu projeto, porque cores pode estar em todos os produtos e produtos pode ter várias cores, então precisa realmente de uma tabela muitos para muitos que pode ser essa corproduto(produto_id, cor_id) seguindo essa idéia. Exemplo eu posso ter  assim (1,1),(1,2), (1,3), (2,1),(2,2) ou seja tem dois produtos ai 1 e 2 com as cores 1, 2 e 3. A idéia principal é essa. Depois é montar a SQL para trazer todas os cores de um determinado produto, como você perguntou e eu fiz um exemplo.

Comment: aquele corstatus é um função que eu coloque para satisfazer e dizer quais estão com 1 e com 0 aonde o 0 não foi selecionado.