# Como nomear tabela pivot Many-to-Many

Tags: laravel

Como nomear tabelas pivot no Laravel, de forma que não seja necessário informar o nome da mesma no método de relacionamento (**belongsToMany**)?

Na documentação achei essa referência:

> Many-to-many relations are slightly more complicated than hasOne and
>   hasMany relationships. An example of such a relationship is a user
>   with many roles, where the roles are also shared by other users. For
>   example, many users may have the role of "Admin". To define this
>   relationship, three database tables are needed: users, roles, and
>   role_user. The role_user table is derived from the alphabetical order
>   of the related model names, and contains the user_id and role_id
>   columns.
>
> ...

Resumindo, é informado que posso pegar o nome dos dois modelo envolvidas e criar uma nomenclatura representando a junção alfabética destes, ou seja, se tenho uma tabela **produto** e outra **usuario**, ficaria **produto_usuario**, com isso não precisaria passar o nome da pivot no método **belongsToMany()**

A questão é, seria a ordem alfabética das models ou migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A questão é, seria a ordem alfabética das models ou migrations?

**No finalzinho da tradução diz**: tradução [Google Tradutor](https://translate.google.com.br/?hl=pt-BR): *A tabela role_user é derivada da ordem alfabética dos nomes dos modelos relacionados e contém as colunas user_id e role_id.*

**Ou seja**, o nome da tabela intermediária começa por ordem alfabética sendo que **R** é antes de **U**, respectivamente `role` e `user` e foi gerado a tabela `role_user`.

Um outro exemplo para esclarecer:

Se no seu projeto for criado duas tabela com o nome de `autor` e `livro` o nome da tabela intermediária seria `autor_livro` e os campos `autor_id` e `livro_id` e a `migration` como exemplo:

> `Migration` autor

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Autor extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('autor', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');            
            $table->string('name', 100)->index();            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }   
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('autor');
    }
}
```

> `Migration` livro

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Livro extends Migration
{    
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('livro', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');            
            $table->string('title', 100)->index();            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('livro');
    }
}
```

> `Migration` autor_livro

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AutorLivro extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('autor_livro', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('autor_id')->unsigned();            
            $table->integer('livro_id')->unsigned();            
            $table->primary(['autor_id', 'livro_id']);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('autor_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('autor');

            $table->foreign('livro_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('livro');

        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('autor_livro');
    }
}
```

e consequentemente seus models:

> `Model` Autor

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Autor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'autor';
    protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];
    protected $fillable = ['name'];    
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function livros()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Livro::class);
    }
}
```

> `Model` Livro

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Livro extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'livro';
    protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];
    protected $fillable = ['title'];    
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function autores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Autor::class);
    }
}
```

mas, vale lembrar que a primeira configuração é obrigatória as demais seguiram a [nomenclatura padrão descrito na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

[Já tem aqui um outro exemplo, mas, diferente desse detalha como deve configurar sem a nomenclatura padrão descrita na documentação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244308/laravel-eloquent-consulta-em-mais-de-uma-tabela/244376#244376) e outros exemplos

- [Laravel checkbox checado ou não checado conforme Banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152789/laravel-checkbox-checado-ou-n%C3%A3o-checado-conforme-banco-de-dados/152918#152918)
- [Salvar varios atributos para um mesmo objeto no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168781/salvar-varios-atributos-para-um-mesmo-objeto-no-laravel/168840#168840)