# inserção no banco com relacionamento N : M

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Preciso inserir usuários no meu banco os dados `MySQL` já com o relacionamento `N:M`, mas não sei como fazer isso.

### Migrate:

```
Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nome');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

 Schema::create('rotas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('action');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

 Schema::create('usuarios_rotas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('usuario_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('usuario_id')->references('id')->on('usuarios');
        $table->integer('rota_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('rota_id')->references('id')->on('rotas');
    });
```

### Model:

```
class Usuario extends Model
{


 protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'email','password'
    ];

public function rotas() {

    return $this->belongsToMany(Rota::class);
}
}

class Rota extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'rota'
];

public function usuarios() {

    return $this->belongsToMany(Usuario::class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Insere o usuário, pegue o id gerado. Insere as rotas, pegue os ids gerados. Insere tudo em usuarios_rotas.

Comment: como vou inserir tudo em usuarios_rotas ?

Comment: pronto editei o post

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, ou então cria uma procedure no banco que recebe um usuário novo e as rotas novas e faz essa ligação

Comment: ah blz man, vou dar uma pesquisada

Comment: Eu escrevi esses dias como deve ser feito para a convenção padrão, se já errou o nome da tabela intermediária que deveria ser rotas_usuarios ...

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274497/como-nomear-tabela-pivot-many-to-many/274509#274509

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Laravel, é bem simples fazer isso. Se você sabe o ID do usuário e o ID da rota, basta apenas usar o método `attach` para fazer isso:

Exemplo:

```
 Usuario::find($usuario_id)->rotas()->attach($rota_id);
```