# Preciso retornar o nome do cliente na View ordens?

Tags: laravel-5

Sou iniciante com o Laravel preciso retornar o nome do cliente na View ordens, no momento esta pegando somente o ID

Classes

```
class Ordem extends Model
{   
    protected $fillable =['id','cliente_id','valor','data','problema',];

    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(produto::class, 'ordem_id');
    }
    public function servicos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(servico::class,'ordem_id');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Cliente extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['id','nome','cpf','endereco','telefone','email'];

    protected $table = 'clientes';  
    public function ordens()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ordem::class,'cliente_id');

    }
}
```

---

```
class OrdemController extends Controller
{    
    public function listaordens()
    {
       $list_ordens = Ordem::all();    
       return view('ordem.listaordens',['ordens' => $list_ordens]);
    }
}
```

View

```
 @foreach($ordens as $o)
 <tr>
    <td> {{$o->cliente_id}} </td>   

    <td class="text-right"> {{($o->data)}} </td>

    <td class="text-center"> {{$o->problema}} </td>

    <td class="text-right"> {{$o->valor}} </td>

    <td class="text-center">
```

Comment: Roni, faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), vote nas respostas que lhe ajudam e também a comunidade.

Answer (score 0):

No `model` `Ordem` adicione a relação com o `model` `Cliente` da seguinte forma:

```php
$this->belongsTo(Cliente::class,'cliente_id', 'id');
```

<sub>***Observação:*** [nesse link tem a explicação de como configurar as relações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel/152108#152108)</sub>

no seu código da classe:

```php
class Ordem extends Model
{   
    protected $fillable =['id','cliente_id','valor','data','problema',];

    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(produto::class, 'ordem_id');
    }
    public function servicos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(servico::class,'ordem_id');
    }
    public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class,'cliente_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

No seu `controller` faça um carregamento adiantado da relação:

```php
$list_ordens = Ordem::with('cliente')->get();
```

no seu classe `controller`:

```php
class OrdemController extends Controller
{    
    public function listaordens()
    {
       $list_ordens = Ordem::with('cliente')->get();    
       return view('ordem.listaordens',['ordens' => $list_ordens]);
    }
}
```

e por fim na `View`

```php
@foreach($ordens as $o)
 <tr>
    <td> {{$o->cliente_id}} </td> 
    <td> {{$o->cliente->nome}} </td> 
    <td class="text-right"> {{($o->data)}} </td>
    <td class="text-center"> {{$o->problema}} </td>
    <td class="text-right"> {{$o->valor}} </td>
    <td class="text-center">
```

Ou seja, precisa configurar a relação da volta, como estava configurado somente **Cliente** para **Ordem**.

***Veja:***

- [Salvar relacionamento 1:1 no Laravel 5.3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3/175886#175886)
- [Problemas com relacionamento um para muitos laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel/152108#152108)
- [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976)
- [Laravel / Eloquent - Consulta em mais de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244308/laravel-eloquent-consulta-em-mais-de-uma-tabela/244376#244376)
- [Laravel checkbox checado ou não checado conforme Banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152789/laravel-checkbox-checado-ou-n%C3%A3o-checado-conforme-banco-de-dados/152918#152918)
- [Como mudar a palavra chave de relacionamento do laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280694/como-mudar-a-palavra-chave-de-relacionamento-do-laravel/280784#280784)

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo retornou o nome certinho

Comment: @RoniCardoso se for útil assinale como resposta do sua pegunta